# How to get current item fields values on clicking button which is inside ListView in android?

Tags: android, listview

I have a android listview which contains a RegNo(present in textview inside listview) value and two buttons allow and deny. on clicking allow button i want to update my MS-SQLdatabase based on RegNo value. please suggest how to create click event for button inside the listview and to get RegNo(textview) value in bacend coding and write update query,

Comment: Can you post the code of your adapter ?

Comment: public class MyListviewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<VisitorListItems> {
    ArrayList<VisitorListItems> visitorlist=new ArrayList<>();
    public MyListviewAdapter(Context context,int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<VisitorListItems> objects)      {
        super(context,textViewResourceId,objects);
        visitorlist=objects;
    }

Comment: @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return super.getCount();
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood your requirement then you are looking for a listener on button. Why don't you try,

```
// Retrieve the TextView first
TextView regView;
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.allow);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
         // Get data from TextView
         String input = regView.getText().toString();
        // Update database
    }
});
```

Refer https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html#ClickListener

Answer (score 1):

To be sure that I have understod you correctly. You have ListView and each item of this ListView have two buttons. Am I right? If yes, than you should just simply assign OnClickListeners right in your getView function.

```
@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.resource, viewGroup, false);

    Button button = view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    TextView text = view.findViewById(R.id.textView);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Logic goes here
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add tag on button

here to set Tag

```
String RegNo="REG NUMBER";
button.setTag(RegNo);
```

here to get Tag

```
public void buttonOnClick(View view){
    String RegNo=(String)view.getTag();
    ... // do your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Override the Interface method onItemSelected() in events callback from the adapterView class, sample is included.

---

```
private OnItemSelectedListener onItemSelectedListener = new OnItemSelectedListener()
{
     @Override
     public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id)
     {
         currentPosition= position;
     }

     @Override
     public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
     {

     }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LinearLayout parent= (LinearLayout)v.getParent();

Button allow= (Button)parent.getChildAt(0);
Button deny= (Button)parent.getChildAt(1);

allow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      //perform your action here
    }
});
```

Comment: Provide atleast some text to explain why this works